# How to get facebook profile picture of user in facebook SDK Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I used facebook 3.6 sdk . i want to get profile picture from graph user , last time i got image but now it returns null Bitmap.

**I used following code**

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        try {
                            URL imgUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"
                                    + user.getId() + "/picture?type=large");

                            InputStream in = (InputStream) imgUrl.getContent();
                            Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgUrl      // tried this also
                            //.openConnection().getInputStream());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }
```

When i use direct link then it works.

```
imgUrl = new URL("https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t39.2365-6/851558_160351450817973_1678868765_n.png");
```

i refered this also [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Auto redirection works automatically when original and redirected protocols are same.

So, try to load images from **https** instead of **http** : "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture"; since image's url is "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/...."

Then `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` shall work again.

Comment: Thanks for the reveal on the redirection.

Comment: i think by putting `&redirect=false` in the url prevent redirection,isn't ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
try {
        URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId()+ "/picture?type=large");
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

here `profile_pic` is your `ImageView` replace it with your `ImageView` Name.

**Edit**

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                   try {
    URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId()+ "/picture?type=large");
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: again bitmap returns _null_

Comment: i tried and i get proper link .When i hit this link in browser then image loads, but Bitmap returns null through code

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public static String getProfilePicture() {

    String stringURL = null;
    try {
        stringURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + URLEncoder.encode(DataStorage.getFB_USER_ID(), "UTF-8") + "?fields=" + URLEncoder.encode("picture", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    LogUtil.log(TAG, "getProfilePicture final url is : "+stringURL);

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    String response = "";

    try {

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(stringURL);
        get.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        get.setHeader("Expect", "100-continue");

        HttpResponse resp = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            resp = httpClient.execute(get);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        // get the response from the server and store it in result
        DataInputStream dataIn = null;
        try {
            //              dataIn = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            if (resp != null) {
                dataIn = new DataInputStream((resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 

        if(dataIn != null){
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
                response += inputLine;
            }

            if(Constant.DEBUG)  Log.d(TAG,"final response is  : "+response);

            if(response != null && !(response.trim().equals(""))) {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            }

            dataIn.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } 

    String profilePicture = "";
    try{
        if(jsonObject != null){
            JSONObject jsonPicture = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture");
            if(jsonPicture != null){
                JSONObject jsonData = jsonPicture.getJSONObject("data");
                if(jsonData != null){
                    profilePicture = jsonData.getString("url");
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LogUtil.log(TAG, "user fb profile picture url is : "+profilePicture);
    return profilePicture;
}
```

Comment: from this url i get profile image , but this image quality is not good.

Comment: @TulsiramRathod Can you share the Image url.

Comment: pls check this https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5.0-1/203169_100000114511793_1329215586_q.jpg

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use redirect page "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/" + USERID + "/picture?type=large" but it didn't work.

It seems that now facebook redirect you to a different page that we cannot guess. Kind of random variables in URL.

So try below method to get the new redirect page provided by facebook.

```
private String getProfileGif(String userId) throws IOException {

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    httpParams.setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects", false);
    HttpGet pageToRequest = new HttpGet("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large");
    pageToRequest.setParams(httpParams);

    AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient
            .newInstance("Android");
    HttpMessage httpResponse = httpClient.execute(pageToRequest);
    Header header = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("location");

    if(header != null){
        return(header.getValue());
    }

    return "";
}
```

This is gonna return you the real gif URL (final URL).

After that, use this new URL to parse your bitmap.

Change from:

```
URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId()+ "/picture?type=large");
```

to

```
URL image_value = new URL(getProfileGif(user.getId());
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

PS: Dont execute getProfileGif or any URL request in main thread.

Let me know your results.